# Authenticate GET requests to files in a folder C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jwplayer

I have a web site (IIS, C#.Net, MVC4) where users are (forms-)authenticated and they upload media files (mostly .mp4) and authorize set of users to play back on demand. I store these files on local storage.

I play these files using jwplayer back to the authorized users on demand. 
jwplayer expects I pass the url directly for it to play, but I didn't want to expose a direct url.
I really have to restrict unauthorized access to these files as they are private files.

I tried implementing a controller method to handle https://mysite/Video/Watch?VideoId=xyz, and return FileStream of the actual file.  It works on a browser directly.  (Though not sure how efficient it is for large files.)

But the problem is, jwplayer looks for urls of pattern http(s)://domain/path/file.mp4[?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2 and so on.]
When I give a url like https://mysite/Video/Watch?VideoId=xyz, it says 'No playable sources found' without even sending a HEAD request.

If I expose the urls directly, the files are available for anybody to download, which will break the privacy.
Worst case, I would at least want to avoid hot links which will live for ever.

I have also looked at www.jwplayer.com/blog/securing-your-content/ but did not find the solutions suitable.

My questions are,

1. Is there a way I can retain the pattern of the url http(s)://domain/path/file.mp4 and still control the access to the file?
2. If (1.) is not possible, how do I leverage the parameters that could be passed on the url. With the parameters, I can think of signed urls.  What should I do on the server if I have to provide and handle/validate signed urls.
3. Just not to hinder the performance, after any validation, can I somehow get the iis to handle the filestream rather my code?

Comment: Writing your own handler for serving mp4 files is fairly trivial, but I assume jwplayer sends HTTP range requests for seeking and streaming which the server would need to support?

Comment: In the JW Player you need to set the variable type to mp4 in your player setup code. That way the player will be able to read the file when the extension is not set.

Comment: Thanks @EthanJWPlayer. I set the type: 'mp4' and jwplayer shows up the thumbnail with no error.

Comment: Thanks @TimRogers. Now, I will try to handle the range requests and see the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented an HTTPModule to allow/block access to the file.  This addresses my questions 1 & 3.
Code snippet below.

```
    void context_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;

        //Get the file extension
        string fileExt= Path.GetExtension(app.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);

        //Check if the extension is mp4
        bool requestForMP4 = fileExt.Equals(".mp4", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        //If the request is not for an mp4 file, we have nothing to do here
        if (!requestForMP4)
            return;

        //Initially assume no access to media 
        bool allowAccessToMedia = false;

        //....
        // Logic to determine access
        // If allowed set allowAccessToMedia = true
        // otherwise, just return
        //....

        if(!allowAccessToMedia)
        {
            //Terminate the request with HTTP StatusCode 403.2 Forbidden: Read Access Forbidden
            app.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
            app.Response.SubStatusCode = 2;
            app.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
```